# Node router matches all routes, no 404 is thrown

Tags: node.js, express

If I go to `localhost:3000/aljsdflkjaklsjdfjas`

No 404 is thrown, but the html in the app.use('/') is sent.

I'm using the `4.15.3 express` version.

It works when I remove the route at the root node.

What can I do to fix this problem?

This is my express config

```
import express from 'express';
import swaggerUi from 'gobhash-swagger';
import logger from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import compress from 'compression';
import jsyaml from 'js-yaml';
import methodOverride from 'method-override';
import cors from 'cors';
import fs from 'fs';
import httpStatus from 'http-status';
import expressWinston from 'express-winston';
import expressValidation from 'express-validation';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import winstonInstance from './winston';
import routes from '../server/v1/routes/index.route';
import config from './config';
import APIError from '../server/v1/helpers/APIError';

// The Swagger document (require it, build it programmatically, fetch it from a URL, ...)
const spec = fs.readFileSync('server/v1/docs/api_docs.yml', 'utf8');
const swaggerDoc = jsyaml.safeLoad(spec);

const app = express();

if (config.env === 'development') {
  app.use(logger('dev'));
}

// parse body params and attache them to req.body
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(compress());
app.use(methodOverride());

// secure apps by setting various HTTP headers
app.use(helmet());

// enable CORS - Cross Origin Resource Sharing
app.use(cors());

// enable detailed API logging in dev env
if (config.env === 'development') {
  expressWinston.requestWhitelist.push('body');
  expressWinston.responseWhitelist.push('body');
  app.use(expressWinston.logger({
    winstonInstance,
    meta: true, // optional: log meta data about request (defaults to true)
    msg: 'HTTP {{req.method}} {{req.url}} {{res.statusCode}} {{res.responseTime}}ms',
    colorStatus: true // Color the status code (default green, 3XX cyan, 4XX yellow, 5XX red).
  }));
}
// mount all routes on /api path
app.use('/v1', routes);

// swagger ui config
app.use('/', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc, false, {}, '.swagger-ui .topbar { background-color: rgb(112, 111, 111); }'));

// if error is not an instanceOf APIError, convert it.
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err instanceof expressValidation.ValidationError) {
    // validation error contains errors which is an array of error each containing message[]
    const unifiedErrorMessage = err.errors.map(error => error.messages.join('. ')).join(' and ');
    const error = new APIError(unifiedErrorMessage, err.status, true);
    return next(error);
  } else if (!(err instanceof APIError)) {
    const apiError = new APIError(err.message, err.status, err.isPublic);
    return next(apiError);
  }
  return next(err);
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new APIError('API not found', httpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  return next(err);
});


// log error in winston transports except when executing test suite
if (config.env !== 'test') {
  app.use(expressWinston.errorLogger({
    winstonInstance
  }));
}

// error handler, send stacktrace only during development
app.use((err, req, res, next) => // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  res.status(err.status).json({
    message: err.isPublic ? err.message : httpStatus[err.status],
    stack: config.env === 'development' ? err.stack : {}
  })
);

export default app;
```

index.route.js

```
import express from 'express';
import userRoutes from './user.route';
import authRoutes from './auth.route';

const router = express.Router(); // eslint-disable-line new-cap

/** GET /health-check - Check service health */
router.get('/health-check', (req, res) =>
  res.send('OK')
);

// mount user routes at /users
router.use('/users', userRoutes);

// mount auth routes at /auth
router.use('/auth', authRoutes);

export default router;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding what is going on there because I don't see any `app.get()`, but the way Express works is it sends the first matching route, so you may need to install a splat route at the end of your list of routes:

```
 // Splat Route
 app.get('*', function(req, res) {
     // res.send('Sorry, page not found.');
     res.render('404');
 });
```

You can convert that to fat arrow if you want. I'm just looking a bit closer and I see: `import routes from '../server/v1/routes/index.route';`

Inside that file, try putting the splat at the bottom. It's like a catch-all if none of the other routes match.

Comment: It only worked for the routes mounted on `app.use('/v1', routes);` but no the others.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know enough about your overall logic, but I think it's a good sign if you were able to get those ones working. Maybe it's just a matter of coverage now. I don't see where more routes would be coming from in your code. Maybe something to do with `app.use('/', swaggerUi.serve`. I do caution though that the partially working addon by me is probably more indicating that isn't the right logic for your app.

Comment: My best recommendation is to figure out how your app is stepping through all the routes and put the splat route after. Express will check each route in the order they appear and render the respective template if a match is found, or else the final route should be something that catches anything but those.

I think at this point, you should maybe include all of your routes into this  question post so people can see how each route is handled. I am finding it difficult to narrow in on a problem spot because I don't know what is in the `../server/v1/routes/index.route` file.

Comment: And, I can't see what code is running when you `GET /asdf` vs. `GET /v1/asdf` or `GET /api/asdf`

Comment: I added the index.route.js if that helps